# How to get angular service in anonymous function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to correctly get $location service. Code below doesn't work because $location in last line is not defined.

```
(function(location, undefined) {'use strict';
    angular.module('mr.activeLink', [])
    .directive('activeLink', [location, function(location) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            }
        };
    }]);
})($location);
```

App module:

```
angular.module('widgetsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate',
    'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'mr.activeLink']);
```

Angular version 1.2.21

Comment: `(function(window, undefined) {'use strict';
    angular.module('mr.activeLink', [])
    .directive('activeLink', ['$location', function($location) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            }
        };
    }]);
})(window);` will work

Comment: @pankajparkar , thank you. I have tried this variant but forgot about the quotes here: `['$location', function($location)`.

Comment: does it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be access `$location` service from dependency.

**CODE**

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('mr.activeLink', [])
    .directive('activeLink', ['$location', function($location) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
               //$location will be available here
            }
        };
    }]);
})(window);
```